# generating a 3d graphics c++

Tags: c++, graphics

I have found an interesting application on the net and i am using it for my end year study project.
http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~sjeh3/wii/ the video in the link explains my goal.
But i am having issue using it. the example of rendering the trajectory on a 3d axis is using Corba (omniorb) and i believe open inventor. but there isn't any idl file. and i don't know if it's possible to use it.
My question is :
Is it possible to render a 3d real time graphics using a lib in c++ making it easy and fast to  implement? i tried using matlab engine or matlab simulation with tcpip communication but i am having issues with these technics so i am searching for another way.
Does anybody have an idea ?
sincerely,
Hugo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might also look at [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) (which uses OpenGL).

**Edit (re: comments)**
For the plotting aspect, you could look at [VTK](http://www.vtk.org/) and/or [MayaVI](https://svn.enthought.com/enthought/wiki/MayaVi) (which puts a Python scripting wrapper around VTK).

Comment: i took a look but there isn't any real lib for a scatter plot whitout having to do plenty of coding. but i am surely wrong !

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [OpenGL](http://www.opengl.org/code/).